# Integrals with an imaginary linear term in the argument of the exponent

Tags: integration, exponential-function

in this entry on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_integrals_in_quantum_field_theory#Integrals_with_a_linear_term_in_the_argument_of_the_exponent) stays

$$
\exp\left(\frac{J^2}{2a}\right)\int_{-\infty}^\infty{\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}a\left(x-\frac{J}{a}\right)^2\right]}dx\quad=\quad\exp\left(\frac{J^2}{2a}\right)\int_{-\infty}^\infty{\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}ax^2\right)}dx
$$
I tried a lot to understand this but still have no idea.
Why is this true?

Comment: Intuitively, as $x$ varies from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, so does $x-\frac{J}{a}$. Or, use the substitution $u=x-\frac{J}{a}$.

Comment: Is $J$ supposed to be the imaginary unit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider a general form
$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x+a) \, {\rm d}x.
$$
With a change of variables $z=x+a$, we get ${\rm d}z = {\rm d}x$, and
$$
I= \int_{-\infty+a}^{\infty+a} f(z) \, {\rm d}z = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(z) \, {\rm d}z.
$$

This change of variables is intuitively a translation of the $x$-axis. But because we are integrating the function over the whole real axis, this translation has no effect.